# Powershell, copy modified time of file to semaphore file

Tags: powershell, null, copy, semaphore, last-modified

I would like to use powershell to copy the modified time from a file to a new file but have the content of the file be nothing.
In command prompt I would use the following syntax:

```
copy /nul: file1.ext file2.ext
```

The second file would have the same modified time as the first file, but the content would be 0 bytes.

The intention is to use the syntax to run a script to check the folder, find file1 and create file2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell open a file for write only (for Lock) and doing 'touch' so to change the file's Last Modified Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156715/powershell-open-a-file-for-write-only-for-lock-and-doing-touch-so-to-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PowerShell v4.0, you can do a pipeline chain using `-PipelineVariable` and have something like this:

```
New-Item -ItemType File file1.txt -PipelineVariable d `
    | New-Item -ItemType File -Path file2.txt `
    | ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime = $d.LastWriteTime}
```

In PowerShell v3.0 (or less) you can just use ForEach-Object loops:

```
New-Item -ItemType File -Path file1.txt `
    | ForEach-Object {(New-Item -ItemType File -Path file2.txt).LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime}
```

I understand that is a little verbose. Cutting it down to aliases would be easy:

```
ni -type file file1.txt | %{(ni -type file file2.txt).LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime}
```

Or you could wrap it in a function:

```
Function New-ItemWithSemaphore {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $args[0] `
    | ForEach-Object {(New-Item -ItemType File -Path $args[1]).LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime}
}

New-ItemWithSemaphore file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you are using existing files, this will work by just getting the item based on a given path:

```
Function New-FileSemaphore {
    Get-Item -Path $args[0] `
    | ForEach-Object {(New-Item -ItemType File -Path $args[1]).LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime}
}

New-FileSemaphore file1.txt file2.txt
```